# Unable to start xampp after installing mongo db php driver with pecl

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, pecl, apache2.4

I have installed php mongodb driver with pecl but when I try to start Lampp I get:

> XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system.

pecl install mongodb seems to run correctly
...

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.1.9
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini
```

I added in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

Configuration

```
os: ubuntu 16.04 
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) 
OpenSSL/1.0.2h 
PHP/7.0.9 
mod_perl/2.0.8-dev 
Perl/v5.16.3
```

How can I fix it?